# Running android emulator using nexus 5 factory image

Tags: android

I've been trying to run the android emulator using nexus 5 factory image.

I've download the factory image and extracted from it the following files:

- *system.img*
- *boot.img*
- *recovery.img*
- *userdata.img*
- *cache.img*

After that, I've extracted from boot.img the ramdisk.img and zImage files.
I tried to run the emulator with the following command:

```
#!/bin/bash

/home/xx/a/android/sources/out/host/linux-x86/bin/emulator -sysdir /home/xx/a/yy/ -system /home/xx/a/yy/system.img -ramdisk /home/xx/a/yy/boot/initrd.img -data /home/xx/a/yy/userdata.img -kernel /home/xx/a/yy/boot/zImage -sdcard /home/xx/a/android/out/sources/sdcard -memory 512 -partition-size 1024
```

The emulator will start running without the error, but it will neither show the boot screen nor load the launcher.

It doesn't show any error and i can't get a logcat, meaning, i guess that android hasn't been loaded and it failed earlier.

Now, my question is - What might the reason for it not to work?